# Android: FireBase storage: Downloading json file as an temporary file

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm more than confused and I tried several things: I want to download a plain text file from FireBase into my local temp file space. This works perfectly. Now I want to use the whole text of this file in my outer class. 
How can I do this?

Here my code snippet:

```
private void getFireBaseStorage() {
    FirebaseStorage storage =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef =
            storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://URL")
                    .child("filename.json");
    try {
        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("file", "json");
        storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.i("FireBase", "File is present " + Long.toString(localFile.length()));
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(localFile);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    String sCurrentLine;
                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        mJSONReturnValue += sCurrentLine;
                    }
                    System.out.println(mJSONReturnValue);
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.i("FireBase", "File is not there");
            }
        });
        // Log.i("FireBase", result.());

    } catch (IOException ioexception) {
        ioexception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was: I tried to download a bigger file from the FireBase storage. The file has approx. 1.3 MB and it takes nearly 3 minutes. With

> .addOnCompleteListener(new
>   OnCompleteListener() {
>            @Override
>            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
>                Log.i(TAG, "Finished");
>                FireBaseStorage.this.returnValue = returnValue;
>                showValue();
>            }

it's possible to return a proper value but it's not so efficient. Maybe this is not the main propose of FireBase storage.

Cheers,
Bjoern